# Can we change the masterpage dynamically based on condition

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two master pages in the project. Based on role i want to use one of the master page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The master page is changed only in `preint` event

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (conduction1)
                this.Page.MasterPageFile = "~/MasterPage.master";
            else
                this.Page.MasterPageFile = "~/Master.master";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: If you try to change master-page in any other method or event it will say that you can change master-page in preinit method only

Comment: Please note: If using MVC, you can change the master using an OnActionExecuted override in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can. You need to do it in the page's `PreInit` event:

```
void page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Page page = sender as Page;
   page.MasterPageFile = "string location of masterpage";
}
```

You need to do this on each `Page`. Master pages are actually part of the page not (as you may expect the other way around).